# Need to access the url in my single view ios application using web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have one issue regarding webview. I have an url and need to run that url in webView.  and my code is here goes..

```
NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);

        UIWebView *webView;
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 470)];
       [webView setDelegate:self];

        NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[encodedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];

        NSLog(@"Response2 ==> %@" ,url1);
        [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
        [[self view] addSubview:webView];
```

`encodedString` is my url which I need to run in `webView` I am getting url value in my output with "" (%22) and opening web view but the content of url not showing.when I use `NSLog` for url1, it showing Response2 ==> %22http://66.541.67.50/mobile%22.

Comment: Did `encodedString` print anything in your Log?

Comment: yes, encodedString is printed in my output, which i need to load in webview exactly.

Comment: Why don't you load your `encodedString` directly into the `url1`

Comment: have you checked the delegated method of the UIWebView http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate , anyone of these delegate hitting, if yes, what is shows,

Comment: Show us your URL value..

Comment: Response ==> "http://68.21.83.56/mobileapp" like that i.e encoded string.

Comment: Did this given anything when you load it into your browser.

Comment: no, it is dummy url,I have a url like that to access.

Comment: Try my updated answer or try with your own url there first in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
url=[NSURL URLWithString:[encodedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this link, it is displaying in web-view

```
NSString *encodedString = @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331396/need-to-access-the-url-in-my-single-view-ios-application-using-web-view";
NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);
```

Change in line :: `[self->webView loadRequest:requestObj];` to `[webView loadRequest:requestObj];`

Rest of the code remains same.

Check in .h file :: `..<UIWebViewDelegate>{...`

It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for opening url in webview.

```
       yourWebview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
      yourWebview.opaque=NO;
     yourWebview.scalesPageToFit=YES;
      [yourWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url string"]]];
```

let me know it is working or not..!!!

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Can you explain what this does?  It's bad form to post code and run; it encourages people to use StackOverflow as a tool to just copy and paste things instead of actually learning about what they do and why they do it.

Comment: first 3 lines are simple, the main code line is 4th line what it does is convert your url(Which is in string obviously) to URL and using that URL we load the request for webview to display the content which is in that URL.

Comment: Well, don't explain it to me!  Edit your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I worked out and the below code works for me....

```
NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);

        UIWebView *webView;
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 470)];
        [webView setDelegate:self];

        NSString *urlAddress = encodedString;
        NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
        NSLog(@"url1 ==> %@" ,url1);
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
        [[self view] addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score -2):

Assigining your `encodedString` into your another `NSString` may be the waste of time. Better you can directly load it into your `url1` as below

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT**

Example -

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Comment: Same as below; that's a readability thing, not an answer to his question.

Comment: @praveen, In my output, url assigned to url1 is showing. but content of url is not displaying in simulator.

Comment: @sudheerchekuri What is your original url?

Comment: @Praveen, its company url.I have no permissions to give over here.

Comment: @praveen, can you give me the gmail, so that I send the code through paste bin.

Comment: @CodaFi, I am getting null value for the url1, I cant able to append or hardcode the url directly as praveen said. can you have any idea hoe to remove the null values.

Comment: @sudheerchekuri Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15331574/940096)

Comment: @Praveen yes, I just used that code snippet.I am getting            url1 ==> %22http://66.221.88.56/mobile%22. we need to remove %22 from url.

Comment: @sudheerchekuri Why did you want to remove that one?

Comment: @Praveen due to %22 in the url, the url is not able to access in the webview mean not able to see the content of url.. thats why, I need to get url without "" as the output

Comment: @sudheerchekuri It won't make any problem to load the content. Problem is with your URL only. Encoding the string for making as URL will not affect anything.

Comment: @Praveen, can you check out the edited question once.. Is there any changes need to be done..to run the url.